# Conditional operator in jQuery template

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-plugins

Does the new jQuery template plugin support conditional(ternary) operator? For printing a simple value depending on a condition, is {{if}}/{{else}} the only option?

I am interested in something similar to `<?=($reviewed ? 'ham' : 'spam')?>`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can put arbitrary functions and expressions inside the [`${}`](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-equal/) template tag:

> Evaluates the specified field
>   (property) on the current data item,
>   or the specified JavaScript function
>   or expression.

```
${reviewed ? 'ham' : 'spam'}
```

So, you could write a template like this:

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <!-- Ternary operator to assign a class -->
    <li class="${Year >= 1990 ? 'orange' : 'yellow'}">
        Title: ${Name}.
        {{each Languages}}
            ${$index + 1}: <em>${$value}. </em>
        {{/each}}
    </li>
</script>
```

Given JavaScript and JSON data like this:

```
var movies = [
{
    Name: "Meet Joe Black",
    Languages: ["French"],
    Year: 1990
}, 
{
    Name: "The Mighty",
    Languages: [],
    Year: 1985
}, 
{
    Name: "City Hunter",
    Languages: ["Mandarin", "Cantonese"],
    Year: 1994
}];

$("#movieTemplate").tmpl(movies).appendTo("#movieList");
```

This applies a class of 'orange' to movies with years greater than or equal to 1990 and a class of 'yellow' to movies with years less than 1990.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/dY43s/

Comment: Working FIne :-)